# displaySingle.imageWrapIfAny wrapp all images insted of single one

Tags: image, wrapper, typo3, tt-news

```
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle {
  imageWrapIfAny = <div class="newsImageWrapper">|</div>
  caption_stdWrap >
  caption_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="captionHolder">|</div>
}
```

Can any one tell me why all my images go into div.newsImage wrapper insisted of single one??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap every single image with a new div, then use this Typoscript:

```
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.imageWrapIfAny >
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.image.wrap = <div class="newsImageWrapper">|</div>
```